# ZkException: Unable to connect to zNode01:2181

Tags: exception, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, znodes

I am new to hadoop so sorry if this seems dumb but here is what is happening.

I am working to setup a multi node kakfa broker so test real time ingestion and as kafka requires ZK it was suggested to best run a replicated ZK.

On the Zookeeper side I can see 1 Leader and 2 Followers.so I wanted to a create a quorom with these three nodes that could be then passed on to my kakfa (by adding an entry in the server.properties file of kafka)

to create this quorom as suggested below

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_RunningReplicatedZooKeeper

I edited my zoo.cfg file to add the below

```
server.5=zNode01:2888:3888
server.2=zNode02:2888:3888
server.1=zNode03:2888:3888
```

where that server.1,2,3 will be my value from the myid file in three ZK instance.

NOTE: I have not re-booted anything yet

so when I go to kafka and try to run

```
./kafka-topics --zookeeper zNode01:2181 --list(to see if any topics exist)

it gives me 

Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zNode01:2181
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:66)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:876)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:51)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: zNode01: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:64)
```

Any help on what I am missing would be great - should I have to restart XK or kafka to accept these changes??

Answer (score 0):

Add the hostname with its address in /etc/hosts file.
System is not able to translate **zNode01**.
Add an entry for **zNode01** in /etc/hosts file.